# PowerShell Script cannot found the npm command after connect to linux via ssh

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, ssh

After connecting to the Linux (Ubuntu) with success, the script executes the command `which npm` with an empty result. I think the npm is not in the script session PATH.

How can I load the user PATH on the script session? Another approach to execute the npm from a Windows console?

In the server with the same user, npm works fine using ssh. The `echo $PATH` shows the npm path too.

```
# Define the SSH connection parameters
$sshParams = @{
    Credential=$userName
    HostName = $sshHostName
    KeyFile = $sshIdentityFile
}

# Connect to the Linux machine using SSH
$sshSession = New-SSHSession @sshParams

$command_npm_install = "which npm;"
Write-Output $command_npm_install
$sshOutput = Invoke-SSHCommand -SessionId $sshSession.SessionId -Command $command_npm_install
Write-Output $sshOutput.Output
```

Comment: Try following $env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ":/ModulePath" which is recommended on following : https://stefanstranger.github.io/2018/11/11/EverythingYouWantedToKnowAboutPowerShellModulePath/

Comment: The problem is with the PATH on the remote Linux server, PSModulePath use the path on the local machine.

Comment: @jdweng, `$env:PSModulePath` is _fundamentally unrelated_ to invocation of _external programs_. Only `$env:PATH` matters for the latter.